# How to monitor the status of standby masters in Alluxio?

Tags: alluxio

In Alluxio, I can monitor the leading master through port 19998. But I also want to monitor the standby master. However, the standby master does not have RPC port 19998. Is there any way to monitor the standby master? I want to monitor the status of the process and check whether the process is working properly. For example, I want to know whether the standby master reads journal timely.
Thanks.

Comment: Please include a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the standby master is alive using `jps` or `ps` and looking for "AlluxioMaster"

```
jps | grep AlluxioMaster
ps ax | grep AlluxioMaster
```

The standby master's log (`logs/master.log`) will report when it reads each journal file. Note that the standby master only reads *completed* edit log files, not in-progress edit log files. By default, the edit log rolls over once it reaches 10MB.

These are some example standby master log messages:

```
2019-03-12 10:59:32,794 INFO  UfsJournalReader - Reading journal file /opt/alluxio/journal/FileSystemMaster/v1/logs/0x0-0x223ff.
2019-03-12 10:59:43,425 INFO  UfsJournalReader - Reading journal file /opt/alluxio/journal/FileSystemMaster/v1/logs/0x223ff-0x441f1.
2019-03-12 10:59:49,152 INFO  UfsJournalReader - Reading journal file /opt/alluxio/journal/FileSystemMaster/v1/logs/0x441f1-0x65ee8.
```